# moveColumns not moving to correct location when column number is lower than target

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently using the moveColumns() function to move a column whenever it is not placed as column J (10). When the column is moved to a higher position, the function correctly moves the column back to J. However, when the column is placed at a lower position, the column is moving to I instead.

My script is as follows currently:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataName = "Data";

  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dataName); // Data sheet

  var barOnePos = 10;
  var barOnePosA1Notation = columnToLetter(barOnePos);
  var barOneName = "Royalty Splits / Rights Management";

  var currBarOnePos = getColumnId(dataSheet, barOneName);
  var currBarOnePosA1Notation = columnToLetter(currBarOnePos) + "1";

  Logger.log(currBarOnePos);
  Logger.log(currBarOnePosA1Notation);

  if (currBarOnePos != barOnePos) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("\"" + barOneName + "\" should be column " + barOnePosA1Notation + ". This will be fixed automatically.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    dataSheet.moveColumns(dataSheet.getRange(currBarOnePosA1Notation), barOnePos);
  }
}
```

Could anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in the case of `When the column is moved to a higher position, the function correctly moves the column back to J.`, the columns below the column "J" are not moved. By this, the column is moved to the correct position.
- On the other hand, in the case of `when the column is placed at a lower position, the column is moving to I instead.`, for example, when the column "A" is moved to the column "J", one column is reduced from the columns below the column "J".

  - I thought that the reason of your issue is due to this.

In order to move the column to the correct position, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
dataSheet.moveColumns(dataSheet.getRange(currBarOnePosA1Notation), barOnePos);
```

#### To:

```
var srcCol = dataSheet.getRange(currBarOnePosA1Notation);
dataSheet.moveColumns(srcCol, srcCol.getColumn() < barOnePos ? barOnePos + 1 : barOnePos);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did end up creating logic similar to this to correct it, but I am still confused as to what exactly is the interaction between moveColumns and onEdit that is causing this. I didn't quite follow the reasoning behind your second bullet point. When a column below J is moved (let's say A), are the columns numbers as 123456789 or 23456789101 at the time that the script calls moveColumns?

Comment: @dan Thank you for replying. About `When a column below J is moved (let's say A), are the columns numbers as 123456789 or 23456789101 at the time that the script calls moveColumns?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of `When a column below J is moved (let's say A), are the columns numbers as 123456789 or 23456789101 at the time that the script calls moveColumns?`?

Comment: I guess another way to put it is, why do we need `srcCol.getColumn() < barOnePos ? barOnePos + 1 : barOnePos`?

Comment: @dan About `I guess another way to put it is, why do we need srcCol.getColumn() < barOnePos ? barOnePos + 1 : barOnePos?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. For example, when the column "A" is moved to the column "J", one column is reduced from the columns below the column "J". When `barOnePos` is used, your issue occurs. By this, `barOnePos + 1` is used. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: this made sense after sitting on it for a while, thanks!